# Capture values from select and text inputs using JS and return output to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that is somewhat like a calculator. A number is entered into a text box and using a dropdown, the user selects a number that is used as a multiplier. 
I can capture the value from the text box properly, however having capturing the value from the select input is tricky.

I'd like this function to be run when the user changes the number in the textbox or changes the option they've selected in the select field.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/b97nkpx0/1/)

```
# HTML
<form>
    <input type="text" id="numberInput"></input>
    <select id="lengthInput">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>

# JS
$(function () {
    var amount = $('#numberInput').val();
    var length_value = ''
    $('#lengthInput').on("change", function () {
        var length = document.getElementById("lengthInput");
        var length_value = length.options[length.selectedIndex].value;
    }).change();
    var calculatedAmount = amount * length_value;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = amount
});
```

Comment: add semi-colon after `var length_value = ''`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reduce what you have to:

```
$(function () {
    $(':input').on('change keyup',function () {
        $('#result').html($('#numberInput').val() * $('#lengthInput').val());
    })
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/b97nkpx0/2/)**

Comment: I love the `:input` selector. One thing to note is that this will add an event handler to **all** form elements, but if the html is as simple as OP displayed, then that selector is boss :)

Comment: @KJPrice - true. If the OP needs to restrict it, it can be changed from `$(':input')` to `$('#numberInput, #lengthInput')`.

Answer (score 2):

To add an event to both your `input` and `select`: change `$('#lengthInput').on("change", function () {` to

`$('#lengthInput, #numberInput').on("change input", function () {`

Then put your `amount` code in the callback. Full code below:

```
$(function () {
    $('#lengthInput, #numberInput').on("change input", function () {
        var amount = $('#numberInput').val();
        var length = $("#lengthInput").val();// <-simplified
        var calculatedAmount = amount * length;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = calculatedAmount
    }).change();

});
```

Comment: `keyup` would be a better choice for an event to use on text inputs. `change` is not triggered for text, on most user agents, until the user moves focus out of the input (when `blur` is triggered). `change` is fine for a radio, it is triggered as soon as the element becomes checked.

Comment: Ah, good point. Wouldn't `input` catch the `keyup` event though?

Comment: Actually `chage` is for the select, and `input` is a better option for `keyup` for input texts, because it works for pasted text (via right click), and it's way faster.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I suppose it would. onInput is not very commonly used in my experience, though. I had to look up the spec to see when it is fired.

Comment: I'd have to see some benchmarks for the "faster" comment, but yeah, it does look like a valid approach. I retract my initial comment, and a +1 for you too :)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks to you both!

Comment: Hmm, more research is required, for sure :) I just asked the other 2 devs here, they'd never even *heard* of onInput. The MDN doc says IE 7 & 8 doesn't play ball, and I can't find any jQuery documentation about it after trivial search, gotta dig deeper. jQuery has a `$.change(...`, but does not appear to have `$.input(...`, and I can't find any indication that support is shimmed in jQuery for oldIE. Take-away, I guess, is test thoroughly in all target user agents before relying on this because, as usual, IE doesn't want you to have any fun at all.